# xml:lang="en-US" doesnt change to "fr" in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, header

How can I get `xml:lang="en-CA"` to change to `xml:lang="fr-CA"` when the user wants to view the website in french instead of English?

`<?php language_attributes(); ?>` toggles the `lang: attribute` to french automatically, leaving it as `lang="fr-FR" and xml:lang="en-US"`.

Bottom line being I cannot change the `xml:lang` attribute to french.

Comment: Does the xml:lang attribute really matter, except as a matter of principle? I would not expect it to affect rendering in any way on current browsers, except possibly on some speech-based user agents, and they hardly know the difference with French in France and French in Canada.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's an option for you but you can hardcode it in your theme file

remove:

```
<?php language_attributes(); ?>
```

add: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr-CA">` you can also check if a certain cookie is set, or a certain user agent is detected to output a custom language by the following pseudocode:

```
$lang='<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="{CODE}">';
if (....){echo(str_replace('{CODE}', "fr-CA",$lang));
} else {
language_attributes();
}
```